# Issue with setting values to a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, polymorphic-associations

I have a model named User . I am using Devise for authentication.
The 'User' has many 'Profiles' and one default profile . So I have added a column called 'default' to the User model. I want to store the id of the default profile. 
However the code fails at the current_user.default = statement.

Error - undefined method `default=' for #User:0x402c480

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

..........
has_many :profiles
...........

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :default

end
```

.......

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user! ,:except => [:show]



  def create
    @profile = current_user.profiles.new(params[:profile])
    @profile.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
      @current_user.default= @profile.id
       ............


end
```

How do I go about this ? Adding 'default' to the User model doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use STI, it means add "type" column into 'profiles' table

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_one  :profile_default

  after_create do
    create_profile_default
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ProfileDefault < Profile
end


def create
  @profile = current_user.profiles.new(params[:profile])
  @profile.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.save
    ...
end
```

Comment: But @mikhailov  what is the issue with '@current_user.default= @profile.id ' ?

Comment: the issue was about usage the 'default' column name or it's type. try to change it to default_id as integer. then @current_user.default_id = @profile.id